# Correction of tags

Tags: support, tags, edits

In this post:

[call to system() does not give expected output in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047684/systempgrep-f-searchword-dev-null-does-not-give-expected-o-p-in-c)

tag "grep" should be "pgrep" (similar name, totally different command).

How can I edit and do a proposal of correction for it? When I try a normal edit, it complains no body text is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pgrep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pgrep) is a synonym of [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep)

[image: Grep]

The tag [pgrep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pgrep) can not be applied to the question because of this. It is automatically converted to [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep)

Comment: thanks. Next question will be "how I can correct a tag definition"?

Comment: Does it need to be? `pgrep` is mentioned in the tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/grep/info

Comment: While "grep" (also "fgrep" and "egrep") looks for regular expressions in file contents or other textual streams, "pgrep" looks for some conditions in the list of processes (one of these conditions can be a regular expression over the process name, but a lot of other are accepted). Going to the extreme, if any program that uses a regular expressions is placed under tag "grep" ...

Comment: TIL. (grep isn't in my area of knowledge). I suggest a meta post asking if pgrep should be split out. Users that are more knowledgeable in that area can weigh in then on whether they should be split (or perhaps explain why they were synonymized in the first place)